# Contains ConcurrentQueue C#

Tags: c#

I am populating a ConcurrentQueue with CSV records from a Parallel operation (Am I using the best collection option?)

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> bag = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

"thisIsID123,they tossed an exception, error5678"
```

I do not see a "Contains" method on this collection. How can I look through the collection to see witch item has "thisIsID123" ?

Comment: You don't see `Contains` because it doesn't really makes no sense to be used with a queue. Perhaps you want a `HashSet<T>`? What operations will you be doing on those strings?

Comment: ConcurrentQueue implements IEnumerable so what about the Contains LINQ extension method?

Comment: @Yuval I am wanting to populate a collection from a Parallel operation. This works fine in doing that. Is there a better option?

Comment: @Daniel im not an expert, can you show me a sample?

Comment: @DanielKelley As soon as the `Contains` returns true, there is no guarantee that the item will exist in queue (it could have been dequed). We can't count on Linq methods for concurrent collections.

Comment: What do you after you populate the collection? Do you enumerate the entire collection? Do you need specific elements?

Comment: @Yuval I look through the collection based on id and use the error info

Comment: If you look on the collection based on ID, perhaps you want a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>` (or `int`, or `long`, depending on the value of id) where id is the key, and the value is the thing you want to operate on.

Comment: @Yuval how do I use a CocurrentDictionary in a Parallel.ForEach. I am just saying theList.Enqueue(aString) now. Can you show me a sample and how to get the info out once the dictionary is populated?

Comment: @nlstack01 `TryGetValue(..)` will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this easily. All you can do with a queue is queue, dequeue or enumerate. To find an element in the queue, you'll need to brute-force search it with a full iteration.

```
foreach(var element in myQueue)
{
    //...
}
```

...or with LINQ

Maybe a more appropriate container might help here? The C5 collections offer a [HashedLinkedList](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.0/c5doc/types/C5.HashedLinkedList%601.htm) which can operate in FIFO mode. It offers the best of both a linked-list (e.g. a queue) and a hash-table for fast access to elements in the middle of the queue. It's not designed for concurrent usage, so you'll have to synchronize your reads and writes with a lock. A quick [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/C5) and you'll have it at your fingertips.

Without knowing too much about your problem domain, I think that placing each entry into a `ConcurrentBag<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>` <strike>(why? because it's the most efficient concurrent collection for insertions and makes very few assumptions about intended usage)</strike> (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the merits of each concurrent collection) and processing the contents of the collection after data acquisition is complete might be preferable. You certainly don't need the ordering offered by a queue as the order of processing in a parallel loop will be indeterminate anyway, so effectively you'll be putting elements into the collection in a semi-random order.

So, in answer to your comment, you could collect everything in a bag:

```
var bag=new ConcurrentBag<Tuple<int, string>>();
var random=new Random();
//lets create some tuples to put in our bag
var objects = Enumerable
                  .Range(0, 1000000)
                  .Select(n= > Tuple.Create(n, n.ToString()))
                  .OrderBy(_ => random.Next())
                  .ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(objects, obj=>
{
    bag.Add(obj);
});
```

Then make a lookup out of the items in the bag, using a specific property as the key (here I use the `Item1` property of the tuples):

```
var lookup = bag.ToLookup(x=>x.Item1);
```

Now you can very quickly look up which tuples in the collection have a specific `Item1` value.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int,string>> itemsOfInterest = lookup[3];
```

You get an enumerable back because there might be more than one item sharing the same property value.

If you can guarantee that your input data has no duplicates, make a dictionary instead:

```
var dic= bag.ToDictionary(x=>x.Item1);
```

then

```
var item = dic[3];
```

Comment: I read that the ConcurrentBag has performance issues over the Queue http://ayende.com/blog/156097/the-high-cost-of-concurrentbag-in-net-4-0

Comment: @nlstack01 That post is measuring the cost of creating many `ConcurrentBag<T>` instances (and the issue appears to be addressed in later versions of .Net). I'm suggesting that you have a single ConcurrentBag into which you place your elements. A different proposition altogether.

Comment: Do you mind showing a sample of populating the bag in a Paralell.ForEach then after the bag is populated getting an element based on the id from above?